# Windows update is installed, but not installed

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, windows-installer

Once upon a time there was a fully functional Windows 7 x64-aware computer, later, dark lord Microsoft released [Security update KB2859537](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39823) and computer was unable to run most of applications. And system administrator decided to uninstall this update from Control Panel, but couldn't find it in "View installed updates" section of "Programs and features" part, but found it in "View update history" section of "Windows update" part.

Then he decided to download that update and run install/uninstall manually, but...

Package listed in registry, but dism doesn't report it with /online - this update is removed from Windows Updates by Microsoft now: http://pastebin.com/J5QpQXg0

[image]

Comment: im lost, you went somewhere on the internet found this update manually, installed it manually, now you want to uninstall it, and you can't

Comment: This update was installed automatically. Now I want to uninstall it.

Comment: Run this command **dism /online /get-packages > packages.log** and upload the log file (pastebin)

Comment: @Ramhound KB 2859537 was one of six patches that where botched by Microsoft and since removed from Windows Update. Search Google for "KB 2859537" and you'll find lots of info about there botched updates. All say the update should be uninstallable via the Control Panel but apparently here it is not found there.

Comment: Exactly, unfortunately this update was also installed at the office, on some computers (via WSUS) and that was real headache to uninstall it. But this particular one was installed on notebook automatically via windows update, but there's nothing we can do. There are hundred of specialized applications installed and I don't want to reinstall it. We were upgrading only Windows.

Comment: @GioMac Are you sure the update is still installed? Do you have any problems related to this update? Perhaps Microsoft already removed it from your computer (minus the registry entries).

Comment: Yes, applications still refuse to start.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is expected situation. Update is still visible in history and is still reported as installed by the installer. Problem was solved by uninstalling newer update - "KB2872339".